# How come the static overload of an operator can call a virtual method of the same class?

Tags: c#, static-methods, equality, equality-operator

I'm poking around with equality in C# and I was implementing something along this line:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyType(string myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }

    protected bool Equals(MyType other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm calling the MyType.Equals override");
        return MyProperty == other.MyProperty;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((MyType) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
    {
        return Equals(lhs, rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var type1 = new MyType("test");
        var type2 = new MyType("test");

        Console.WriteLine($"type1 == type2 => {type1 == type2}");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

and the output is

> I'm calling the MyType.Equals override
>   type1 == type2 => True

while I'm fully aware of the possible surprises that would arise by overriding the equality operator this way, what I'd like to know is why it's possible to end up calling an instance virtual method (protected bool Equals(MyType other) in MyType class) from a static method.
Ok, it doesn't really look like a static method given the

> operator

keyword but, as far as I can tell, it gets translated as a static method in IL:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static bool  op_Equality(class MyType lhs, class MyType rhs) cil managed
```

I suspect that the magic happens somewhere in the object.Equals static method calls but I don't know how it actually works. Care to shed a light on?

Comment: Putting a breakpoint in that method, debugging your code and inspecting the call stack is fairly basic debugging and would let you see the series of calls that are involved.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my stupid doubt had nothing to do with the call stack but, for some reason, it just didn't click to me that a static method can call instance methods of other objects. I don't know exactly why I had this doubt for this particular case, it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic - and you can implement similar code yourself just fine.
[`Object.Equal(object,object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx) which you use eventually calls `left.Equals(right)` producing result you see:

> If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result. This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method, this override is called.

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
{
    return Equals(lhs, rhs); // calls Object.Equal(object,object)
}
```

the code is roughly equivalent to following inline implementation:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyType lhs, MyType rhs)
{
    if (lhs == null || lhs == null) 
    {
        // this branch is not executed in your sample
        return RefrenceEquals(lhs,rhs);
    } 
    return lhs.Equal(rhs); // calls override bool Equals(object obj)
    // which in turn calls 
    // bool Equals(MyType other) since both are other is not null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any magic. The `Equals` method is virtual on `object` and you are overriding it - so when calling `((object)lhs).Equals`, of course your overriden method is called. And that's what the static `object.Equals` you are calling does :) The same thing happens if you call `Equals` anywhere else, operators really are just static methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when accessing a static member(field/method/etc) inside a class itself (as well as its derived classes), the type identifier can be omitted.

```
class A
{
    public static int Number = 0;

    protected static void MA()
    {
        var n = Number;    // var n = A.Number;
    }
}
```

In the derived classes:

```
class B : A
{
    public static void MB()
    {
        var n = Number;   // var n = A.Number;
        MA();             // A.MA();
    }
}
```

Since every class derives from `System.Object`, the public static method `Object.Equals` can be accessed from every classes, with `Object.` omitted.